# Error in java file ,yosemiteadapter.java(ViewPageAdapter), making an tour app, app is crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I am making a tour app, it structure is like this:

First activity shows seasons like Summer, Winter, Spring, Autumn. After selecting any season, another activity pops up with locations around the world best suited for that season. After selecting any one location, another activity will pop up with 2 to 3 images with the description, and we will slide through these images. That's it. To make it more accessible, I tried adding this code to NawDrawer activity:

[image: Check This Image]
[Debugging Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO9cG.jpg)

Originally the ViewPagerAdapter.java was for Hawaii (check the image), but I created exact same as Yoshimiteadapter.java for Yosemite, but it's not working.

I apologize for the inconvenience caused by the files :) ,it's messy ,but desperate help is needed:
[Link to android studio project zip file](https://www5.zippyshare.com/v/G4qJsbLn/file.html)

There are total 7 java files and 12 activity files although I have an error in **yosemiteadapter.Java line no 35 ,** error message is as follows:

> 04-16 12:00:09.563 12511-12511/com.example.android.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.android.myapplication, PID: 12511
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>           at com.example.android.myapplication.yoshimiteadapter.instantiateItem(yoshimiteadapter.java:35)

**Code for the app as follows,I have block quoted the line of error **

**yoshimiteadapter.java**

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by sanchitdeshmukh on 17/03/18.
 */

public class yoshimiteadapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private  Integer []images1 ={R.drawable.yosemite1,R.drawable.yoshemite2,R.drawable.yoshemite3};
    private Integer []strings1 = {R.string.yoshimite};
    public yoshimiteadapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_yos, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images1[position]);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(strings1[position]);


        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

}
```

**yosemite.java**

```
    package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class yoshemite extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_yoshemite);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.yoshimite);
        yoshimiteadapter yoshimiteadapter = new yoshimiteadapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(yoshimiteadapter);
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
    package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by sanchitdeshmukh on 17/03/18.
 */

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private  Integer []images ={R.drawable.napalicoast,R.drawable.haleakaaa,R.drawable.roadtohana};
    private Integer []strings = {R.string.haleaka,R.string.napali,R.string.Paragraph_hawaii};
    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(strings[position]);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution , it's related to this:

```
textView.setText(strings1[position]);
```

I have only one string, three images, which causes the error. `[position]` should be set to `'0'`; so the modification is like this:

```
textView.setText(strings1[0]);
```